# If $A^m=I$ then A is Diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix. If $A^m=I_n$ for some positive integer $n$. How to show that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

What we can say for the polynomial $x^m-1$?

Comment: $x=\pm 1$.. I think i got it

Comment: @Danial A little more! You're in $\Bbb C$, not (algebraically) boring $\Bbb R$!

Comment: @Danial What if $m$ is odd?

Comment: @Danial so as not to tease you - what you should notice is that the polynomial has no multiple roots

Comment: I am trying the following: $A=P^{-1}JP\Rightarrow A^m=P^{-1}J^mP=I_n\Rightarrow J^m=I_n$ but i don't see what can i do further.. I don't know how to use the hint above .. i feel i stupid

Comment: @Danial $A$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial splits into linear factors so with the given hypothesis of your question can we say that we have this condition?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff:  Not to be contentious, but I think $\Bbb R$ is at least as interesting as $\Bbb C$.  That is to say, $\Bbb C$ is no more boring than $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff:  algebraically and/or otherwise! ;)

Comment: @Danial notice, as $x^m - 1$ has no duplicate roots, it is irreducible, and $0 = A^m - I = (x^m - 1)[A]$ by requirement.
From this we have: 1. $\mu(x) = x^m - 1$ is irreducible, 2. $\mu(A) = 0$.
$$$$
Conclusion?

Comment: Yes thank you all .. I solved it :)

Comment: @RobertLewis Sure. The above was merely a joke to hint on what the OP was missing.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff:  As was my remark, albeit directed toward the general readership, since I admit it didn't really address the question at hand.  Humor and math, great together or separately!

Comment: It's interesting to note that using this technique you can actually prove the somewhat stronger result: if $A$ is a complex matrix (or a matrix over any alg closed field with characteristic prime to the integer $m$ about to appear) such that $A^m$ is diagonalizable for some $m$, then $A$ is diagonalizable. This follows because $m_A(x)\mid m_{A^m}(x^m)$ and by assumption $m_{A^m}(x^m)$ is separable and splits in the field.